# How Javascript decides when new line character separates statements?

Tags: javascript

For example, following code prints 1, which means that new line is treated as statement separator:

```js
function f1() {
    return 1
    2
}

console.log(f1());
```

However, this example prints 3, which means that new line is ignored:

```js
function f1() {
    return 1
    +2
}

console.log(f1());
```

How does Javascript decides when to ignore new line character, and when use it as a statement separator?

Comment: To oversimplify a bit, it assumes that a newline ends a statement if it would otherwise be a syntax error. `return 1 2` is a syntax error, whereas `return 1 +2` is not.